# word VBA macro sorting

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, selection, list

I have a structured text:

```
hello, hellos <xxxyyy>; nice, nicer <uuuvvv>; great, greater <wwwzzz>;
```

and would like to write the three text pieces between < > under each other:

```
xxxyyy
uuuvvv
wwwzzz
```

I was searching in the questions asked before, but still do not know how to start setting up a VBA macro that would select and list these.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: are your sample data in the same cell, or in multiple cells?

Comment: the sample data are in word. it is a single line.

Comment: no, I did not try much before, because first I like to know the approach.

Comment: what I mean is the following: Shall I read character by character till "<" is found, then write to a line, till ">" is found, then command to start writing to  next line, etc

Comment: I think the code should make use of:                                                    Sub SelectTextBetweenBookmarks()

    Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Start").Range
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("End").Range

    Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use VBA to solve this, can do it with find and replace:

1. copy your target range to a new location where you need to get the list and select it.
2. open find and replace dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
3. press "More" and select "Use wildcards"
4. For "find what" enter `[!<]@\<([!>]@)\>[!<]@`
   (you can read more on regular expressions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f))
5. For "replace with" enter `\1^13`
6. press "replace all"

Comment: well, I tested...and...it works flawlessly!!! one thing to remember is to remove hyperlinks in the word document. Best regards, Marcel